# unique entity validation for add and edit forms

Tags: validation, symfony, entity, unique

I use unique entity validation in username property of user entity, 
when the user is going to be added that is ok, 
but when the user is going to be edited, and username is not changed the unique entity validation impede this, because the same object already exist with that username, 
how can I handle this?
PD:sorry for my poor english

Comment: Can you show to us some code? How are you persisting and updating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [validations groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups). Link your UniqueEntity constraint to a validation group `"new"`, then only link this group to your form when you are creating a User.

Comment: thanks for answer, i think that this can be the solution, maybe if i compare the old and

Comment: thanks for answer, i think that this can be the solution, maybe if i compare the old and new usernames, and if they are not equals then i use the validation group "new" whit uniqueentity validation because is needed, but if they are equals then i use the validation group "edit" without uniqueentity validation